# How to set variable height based on various screen resolutions using css and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with 300px static height and another div with dynamic height below the static div. The div should be dynamic based on screen resolution can anyone help me out...

```
<div class="static" style="height:300px;width:100%">
</div>
<div class="dynamic">
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like this is what you are looking for: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
html,body{height:100%;}
.dynamic{
  height:calc(100% - 100px);
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="static" style="height:100px;width:100%">
</div>
<div class="dynamic">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `height: calc(100vh - 300px);`

```
<div class="static" style="height:300px;width:100%">
</div>
<div class="dynamic" style="height: calc(100vh - 300px);">
</div>
```

Comment: Won't work unless parent element has height to fill page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="static" style="height:300px;width:100%">
</div>
<div class="dynamic">
</div>
<style>
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.dynamic{
  height:100px;
  } 
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
.dynamic{
  height:200px;
  } 
} 
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
.dynamic{
  height:300px;
  } 
} 
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {
.dynamic{
  height:400px;
  } 
} 
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
.dynamic{
  height:500px;
  } 
}
</style>
```

Comment: Is their any other solutions so that i can my code weight reduces?

Answer (score 0):

I added a wrapper with height as 100vh. I read 1vh=1% of browser height, and 100vh equals 100% height. With the height set at 100vh, flex can fill the area. Check this:

```css
    .wrapper{
      display:flex;
      flex-direction:column;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    .static{
      height:300px;
      width:100%;
      background-color: steelblue;
    }
    .dynamic{
      display:flex; 
      flex:1;
      background-color: lightgreen;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="static" style="height:300px;width:100%">Static Div</div>
  <div class="dynamic">Dynamic Div</div>
 </div>
```